# How to call helper method from model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I use MongoDB as a database in my Rails application with MongoID gem. I want to call the helper method from the model within `after_create` callback method. How is it possible?
My model code is:

```
class Department
  include ApplicationHelper
  after_create :create_news
  private
  def create_news
    @user = ApplicationHelper.get_current_users
  end
end
```

And my helper code is:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def get_current_users
    current_user
  end
end
```

When I create new department then following error occur.

```
undefined method `get_current_users' for ApplicationHelper:Module
```

How to remove error?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you making this a helper? Helpers tend to be used to generate markup for your views. This method looks like it belongs in a model.

Comment: I make this helper to get current user information in model.

Comment: Make it a method in your model instead then?

Comment: I can't use current_user in model. So I tried alternative

Comment: my actual problem is:
https://www.quora.com/Ruby-on-Rails/What-are-good-ways-to-get-current-user-detail-in-models

Comment: I've marked this down because you've asked the question (basically) again already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089355/what-are-good-ways-to-get-current-user-detail-in-models

Answer (score 23):

I also use `mongoid` and use this all the time. Shouldn't be unique to `mongoid` though.

```
ApplicationController.helpers.my_helper_method
```

Comment: This appears to have been intentionally-broken in later rails versions, because team-rails thinks we should not do this.  So just 'repeat yourself' and add a comment in both locations, so you know to change it in both locations at the same time.  Or, you can use 'module' functionality - but that is overkill for small things.

Comment: This works for me in Rails 7.1

Answer (score 4):

If you want a helper method that you can use in your views to return the current user, you can do so in your `ApplicationController`, something like this for example:

```
private
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end 
helper_method :current_user
```

Then you can use this in any view.

If you want some arbitrary method in a model to know what user it's dealing with, **pass** `@current_user` **in as an argument to the method when you call it in your controller**.

Your code seems incomplete so I can't really see what you're trying to accomplish, but this is pretty standard practice.

Comment: How to get the value of @current_user in model

Comment: @gami Your controller typically handles instantiating a model and passing data to it. Pass `@current_user` to it as you would any other piece of data. You should post more of your code, like your controller where you use this model.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the module file is named properly, meaning in your case `application_helper.rb` and it's located on the helpers library.

You can also try to include the helper in the ApplicationController (**app/controller/application_controller.rb**).