# What are good ways to get current user detail in models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, module, mongoid

I used devise gem for authentication in my rails application. I want to get certain information about current user on after_create callback. How is it possible? 
My model code is:

```
class Department
  field :name
  after_create :create_news
  private
  def create_news
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

But when I create new department I get following error.

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Department:0x00000005b51648>
```

What is the best way for this?

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to ever have the need to refer to the `current_user` inside a model, and should you really need it, you would pass it in to a method

Comment: Don't double post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088945/how-to-call-helper-method-from-models his is the same question in another form as the one you've just asked

Answer (score 2):

Access control in rails is done at the controller level, not the model level.  As a result, rails provides no mechanism for accessing the current user, cookies, etcetera, from inside model code.  You can ferry the data into the model by parameters to methods, if you choose.  However, that would be ignoring the design decisions of some of the best programmers in the industry, so I think it's probably not a good choice.

In other words, don't do what you're trying to do.  Put the knowledge of how to do things in your model, but put controls around who can do them in the controller.

On the other hand, if you're trying to store the current user for some reason, then you should do that by some sort of association (or nested document, since you're using mongo).  In that case, don't use `current_user` inside the model, but rather make an `attr_accessor` on user, set the user on the instance of your model to the `current_user` in the controller, and then save it how you need to in your callback.

Answer (score -2):

current_user is only available to controller and views. If your `department` model is connected to `user` model,you should add `belong_to` association and can do something like

```
after_create :create_news
def create_news
 @current_user = self.user
end
```

Comment: my department model is not connected to user model. How is it possible in this case?

Comment: The answer, unfortunately, is that rails is an opinionated framework, and one of it's opinions is that you just shouldn't do that.  You can try to fight it if you choose, but then it turns into ruby off rails, which is no fun...

Comment: @Passionate this is a really unconstructive answer and comment.

Comment: I apologise for providing poor answer, but i want to know in what terms it is poor and down voted so that I can may not repeat same mistake.

Comment: Don't write 'what you're doing is rubbish'. I see where you're coming from with your answer but it takes a lot of interpretation and you've made a big assumption. Try and be clearer and you'll get more votes